# automate settings change on multiple power appliances

Tags: bash, scripting, python, power-distribution-unit, automated

I'm trying to automate the task of changing settings on 100+ power appliances via SSH but each settings change has multiple interactive prompts. Is this possible or does anyone have an example of how to do this with Python/bash script?

Answer (score 2):

Look into [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). Alternative implementations for other languages and systems than Tcl exist (e.g. [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for Python or the [Ansible expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/expect_module.html)).

For 100s of devices, I would particularly look into the Ansible module (I am sure similar modules exist for other systems like salt or chef).

Comment: OK, so still nothing better than expect, but Ansible has an expect module... that sounds interesting.

Comment: @Law29: I've not used it, but at least for somewhat simple cases, pexpect doesn't look too bad.

Answer (score 1):

The cloud-generation answer to your question is a programmer-friendly REST API over HTTPS, which your appliances do not seem to have.

The canonical decades-old answer to your question is [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). There is a learning curve there, which may not be worth it when comparing to writing a custom python script,  especially if you already know python or if you might want someone else to maintain it in the future.

Between the two, I suspect that writing your custom python script will be the least bad solution, unless some other friendly person here has knowledge of a tool that has escaped my notice.